# save your app data when redownloading

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, save

I am creating an app and I was wondering if there is a way to save the data that you insert into the emulator for re-downloading?  if so can you please tell me how.

Comment: please explain what redownloading and all this means with maybe an example of what you do and expect to happen.

Comment: I am trying to make an app that takes the value of an edit text an checks to see if that value is in an array.  I would like that when I click the run app button and choose an emulator the edittext values stay in the array and I dont need to retype them into the edittext.